# Symfony - Using collectionType length as counter in prototype twig template doesn't work

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, prototype

I tried a lot, but I can't get this to work.

I'm using a Form with a CollectionType (ChoiceType) in Symfony 4.
In my form, you can add children (literally children - small young people :) - it is an age choice field).

For this, I added one default child.

In my form row, I want to use ids, label etc with the current number of the child.
e.g. I want the label of each child to be like "Child 1", "Child 2" and so on.

First the code:
ChildField in FormType

```
->add('childs', CollectionType::class, [
    'allow_add' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
    'entry_options' => [
        'choices'  => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
    ],
    'data' => [
        1 => 0,
    ]
]);
```

My template for the field row

```
<div class="form-group row" id="childsupport_child_{{child_number}}_formgroup">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="childsupport_child_{{child_number}}_toplabel"><b>{% trans %}childsupport.child{% endtrans %} {{child_number}}</b></div>

    <div class="col-sm-8" id="childsupport_child_{{child_number}}_label" for="childsupport_childs_{{child_number}}">{% trans %}childsupport.childAge{% endtrans %}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ form_widget(childField) }}

    </div>
    {% if child_number > 1 %}
    <div class="col-sm-1" id="childsupport_child_{{child_number}}_delete"><span class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_child({{child_number}})">X</span></div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to use the variable {{child_number}} in this template.
I'm using the template via macro.

```
[...]
{% import _self as formMacros %}
[...]
{% macro printChildRow(childField, counter) %}
    {% include 'childsupport.child.html.twig' with {'childField': childField, counter} %}
{% endmacro %}

[...bla bla form starts, other field get printed...]

<div class="js-child-wrapper" data-prototype="{{formMacros.printChildRow(childsupport_form.childs.vars.prototype, childsupport_form.childs|length+1)|e('html_attr') }}"
         data-index="{{ childsupport_form.childs|length }}"
    ></div>
    {% for childField in childsupport_form.childs %}
        {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
        {{ formMacros.printChildRow(childField, counter) }}
    {% endfor %}
[...bla bla submit button, form ends...]
```

I'm trying to pass the current collection length+1 as counter.

An at last the js.

```
function add_child(){
    var wrapper = $('.js-child-wrapper');

    var prototype = wrapper.data('prototype');
    var index = wrapper.data('index');
    var newChild = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index+1);
    $(newChild).insertAfter( "#childsupport_child_"+index+"_formgroup" );

    wrapper.data('index', index + 1);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= index; i++) { 
        $('#childsupport_child_'+i+'_delete').hide();
    }

}
```

This works for the first time.
childsupport_form.childs|length+1 is 2 then and the second child is correctly added.
But then it doesn't work anymore.

So I got the feeling, that childsupport_form.childs|length is not a dynamic value that changes in the process of the addition of CollectionFields.

What do I need to pass instead as second variable for the prototype in this line?

```
<div class="js-child-wrapper" data-prototype="{{formMacros.printChildRow(childsupport_form.childs.vars.prototype, childsupport_form.childs|length+1)|e('html_attr') }}"
         data-index="{{ childsupport_form.childs|length }}"
    ></div>
```

Or am I completely on the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: templates happen server-side, js happens client-side. that means, that the prototype you generate is only generated on the server request and stays the same for the user client-side, no matter how many children they add. every form has a label property which you can probably use. for the prototype the label usually contains `__label__` or something. everything inside `{{}}` will remain static leaving the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cleary that doesn't work this way... I did some research on __label__ but didn't find anything useful for now. I still hope, that there is a solution for this problem :)

Comment: the real proper way would be to correctly provide a form theme to render your form (with `form_widget(...)` as it is supposed to be rendered). it's somewhat complex and confusing but might ultimately solve all your problems. for a quick fix, I'd assume it's not worth the effort to learn it

Comment: Well, I already started a form theme for the other forms. The difficult thing is to determine how to combine form themes with the usage of prototypes and to implement the variables in there. But you're right! Let's do it in the next project ;)

Comment: `data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.vars.prototype) }}"` is pretty much the way to combine the two. the `form_widget` will receive the same stuff it will usually receive except that the form names and labels will have place holders in them, namely `__name__` and `__label__`, which you would have to replace in js.

Comment: Ok, but that still leaves the problem: How do I replace __name__ and __label__ in twig? Because the initial datasets are created in twig via foreach

Comment: the same way you did so far: `var newChild = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index+1);` replaces the counter in the `name`, you just need to replace `/__label__/` as well with some sensible text, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, but the initial Collection Items are created it twig and not in js...

Comment: a prototype is a kind of "form template", that can be turned into a proper form (read: something that symfony will understand when sent) via javascript. js on its own without the prototype doesn't "know" how to create the correct form, but with the prototype and some basic logic, as you already have, it should work. except of course, when your form rendering is too specific.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary, I used the quick and dirty solution and cloned the childsupport.child.html.twig to childsupport.child_prototype.html.twig, where I used **name** instead of {{child_number}}.

So, I used the first template for the initial creation of the predefined collection values and the cloned one for the onClick Event.

Works.

But still quick and dirty.